# Pandas Dataframe: How to take the value from column A to join each value of a list in column B?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say, I have a Dataframe:

```
| ColumnA  | Column B |
|----------|----------|
| prefix_1 | [A, B]   |
| prefix_2 | [C, D]   |
```

And I expect to get a new DataFrame like:

```
| ColumnA  | Column B | Column C                 |
|----------|----------|--------------------------|
| prefix_1 | [A, B]   | [prefix_1-A, prefix_1-B] |
| prefix_2 | [C, D]   | [prefix_2-C, prefix_2-D] |
```

How do I need to do this transfer? Thank you.

I tried below but didn't work:

```
df['ColumnC'] = df['ColumnB'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: [df['ColumnA'] + '-' + e.strip() for e in x]).tolist()
```

Comment: The input and output types are unclear, please provide the output of `df.to_dict('list')` on your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in using a `lambda` function, but I would use it like this:

```py
# Create the dataframe from your question
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA': ['prefix_1', 'prefix_2'], 'Column B': [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]})

# Create Column C accordingly
df['Column C'] = df.apply(lambda row: [row['ColumnA'] + '-' + elem for elem in row['Column B']], axis=1)
```

Make sure that you use `axis=1`, so that the lambda funcion applies row-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension.

If you have lists in Column B:

```
df['Column C'] = [[f'{p}-{x}' for x in l] for p, l in
                   zip(df['ColumnA'], df['Column B'])]
```

If you have strings in Column B:

```
df['Column C'] = [[f'{p}-{x}' for x in l] for p, l in
                   zip(df['ColumnA'],
                       df['Column B'].str[1:-1].str.split(',\s*')
                       )]
```

And if you want a string as output:

```
df['Column C'] = ['['+', '.join([f'{p}-{x}' for x in l])+']'
                  for p, l in
                   zip(df['ColumnA'],
                       df['Column B'].str[1:-1].str.split(',\s*')
                       )]
```

Output:

```
    ColumnA Column B                  Column C
0  prefix_1   [A, B]  [prefix_1-A, prefix_1-B]
1  prefix_2   [C, D]  [prefix_2-C, prefix_2-D]
```

Reproducible inputs:

```
# as string
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA': ['prefix_1', 'prefix_2'],
                   'Column B': ['[A, B]', '[C, D]']})

# as lists
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA': ['prefix_1', 'prefix_2'],
                   'Column B': [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]})
```